# h:inputText allow only decimal digits

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I need to restrict the inputtext using onkeypress event to allow only numbers and decimal. i am able to restrict numbers but its not allowing dot value.

```
<h:inputText value="#{dimStackLine.max}"
  onkeypress="if( (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) ) return false;">
  <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"></p:ajax>
  <f:convertNumber pattern="####0.00000" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: This is a plain jsf inputText, nothing PrimeFaces related

Comment: yes just plain jsf

Comment: It even comes down to plain HTML and JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input of decimal dot `.` is prevented by your `onkeypress` because the event key code is 46 which is not within the allowed range of `48 <= code <= 57`. You have to allow code 46 additionally:

```
<h:inputText value="#{dimStackLine.max}"
  onkeypress="if( (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) &amp;&amp; event.which != 46 ) return false;">
  <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"></p:ajax>
  <f:convertNumber pattern="####0.00000" />
</h:inputText>
```